# How to not repeat myself while making similar components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So this is more of a stylistic question say I have 2 components

```
Components
  - LoginPage
    - LoginPage.jsx
    - loginPage.module.css

  - RegisterPage
    - RegisterPage.jsx
    - registerPage.module.css
```

Both LoginPage and RegisterPage look the exact same pardon a few words but all the styles are the same.
how should I go about organizing that or structuring that to where I dont have to write the same css and or jsx twice in both components. I know I could put the styles in index.css and have them be global styles but that would get rid of the use for css modules I feel. any help appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is all about reusablity of the component. So you can use the styling `css` or JSX in both by creating a seperate component. Consider the below example.

Suppose `Login.jsx` look like this

```
function Login() {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Password" />
       <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

And few change in `Register.jsx` i.e only added a new field `confirm password` So

```
function Register() {
      return (
        <div className="wrapper">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
           <input type="text" placeholder="Password" />
           <input type="text" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
           <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Now it's totally your call to use the DOM in both `login.jsx` and `register.jsx` or copy/paste the css in both the pages.

But if your `wrapper` className has too many css property defined or your input field have certain custom animations defined then you can break the same into multiple component like below example.

```
function Wrapper({children}) {
  return (
   <div className="wrapper">
      {children}
   </div>
  )
}
```

and all the `CSS` properties for wrapper will go inside Wrapper.css file which contains the css for only wrapper.

Now to reuse the `Wrapper` HOC you need to call in both `Register` and `Login`

So Use Following way to call Wrapper in both the file.

```
function Login() {
      return (
        <Wrapper>
           <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
           <input type="text" placeholder="Password" />
           <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </Wrapper>
      )
    }
```

and in Register.jsx

```
function Register() {
          return (
            <Wrapper>
               <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
               <input type="text" placeholder="Password" />
               <input type="text" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
               <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </Wrapper>
          )
   }
```

So this way you can use the CSS of `wrapper` class in both `Login.jsx` and `Register.jsx`.

It is helpful for `Input` field as well.

If you have common `CSS` or you need common validations for input field then you can define a seperate component name `Input` such that you can just import the `Input` and it will inport the CSS of input as well.

When you donot have any such `CSS` defined for input or you feel that It will not be used in other places then better go for repeating the element in the pages.

It is helpful for `Auth` as well. The `Auth` check logic can be passed to most higher component.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a single component like `Auth.js` which receives props like `type` either `Login` or `Register` and can manipulate views accordingly so It will help you to get rid of the duplication.

Comment: Alright I was thinking something like that but it seemed kinda hacky but if thats the best way to do it ill just do that. thanks